# Hyper-V stopped working after January 2022's Patch Tuesday (2022-01-11): The operating systems boot loader failed with error 0xC00000BB

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

- I only just noticed this now, but apparently since 2022-01-11 ("Patch Tuesday" in January 2022) my home network's dev-server's Hyper-V hypervisor has been unable to start.

  - The box is a 6 year-old Xeon E3 machine (UEFI of course), running Windows Server 2012 R2 with the Domain Controller and Hyper-V host roles installed.
- The Hyper-V Event Logs are littered with errors, but those are all second-order consequences of the initial service failure which is reported with this event in the System event log:

  > Level: Error
  > Source: Hyper-V-Hypervisor
  > Event ID: 80
  >
  > Hypervisor launch failed; The operating systems boot loader failed with error 0xC00000BB.

  - The raw XML of the Event says that the `0xC00000BB` code is an `NTSTATUS` error code, [which apparently means "`STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED`"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) - which doesn't make any sense as Hyper-V was working fine before Patch Tuesday and I'm not aware of Intel pushing-out any processor microcode updates to disable hardware virtualization like some kind of horrible SPECTRE/MELTDOWN-esque mitigation...
- As it happened right after patch Tuesday, I'm guessing Microsoft botched a Hyper-V patch - and I probably shouldn't be expecting the best quality-control for security patches for 8.5-year-old OS releases...
- Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more Google-fu, [I found this thread on HP Enterprise's public forum](https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/ML10-G9-Hyper-V-not-starting-upon-Windows-2012-R2-january-11/td-p/7158113) and a reply from user *MDavidRichard* attributes the failure to Microsoft update KB5009586:

> No it's nothing to do with HPE. Just remove the Microsoft update KB5009586 and reboot...
>
> Good luck!

Microsoft's page for [KB5009586](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/january-11-2022-kb5009586-monthly-rollup-9541f57c-89b0-48d6-ade2-31609678ce9b) is now updated with a *Known Issue* that describes my issue (though without any googleable error-codes, no wonder I didn't find this page earlier):

> After installing this update on a device by using Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI), virtual machines (VMs) in Hyper-V might not start.
>
> This issue is resolved in [KB5010797](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb5010797-out-of-band-update-for-windows-server-2012-january-17-2022-1f14f497-8404-404d-8d78-0c962c9e486d).

However I don't see KB5010797 in Windows Update's available downloads list...

**UPDATE:** Ah, derp, the KB5010797 patch is for Windows Server 2012 (*not* Server **2012 R2**) while KB501079**4** is for Windows Server 2012 R2.

### TL;DR:

Install KB5010797 or KB5010794 depending on your OS.